# Codeigniter encode / decode different result for same string. Normal?

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

In my custom config i have a line like:

```
$config['encryption_key_posts'] ='vfy9SbKO!drtzwHkOvD46hGFedzaw3$l';
```

In a custom library i have:

```
class MyEncryption {

public $_CI;
public function __construct() {
    $this->_CI = & get_instance();
    $this->_CI->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH);
    $this->_CI->encrypt->set_mode(MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
}
function encode($str, $key) {
    return $this->_CI->encrypt->encode($str, $key);
}
function decode($str, $key) {
    return $this->_CI->encrypt->decode($str, $key);
    }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
encode($_POST['post_title'],config_item('encryption_key_posts'))
```

and

```
decode($this->data['post']->post_title,config_item('encryption_key_posts'))
```

I am testing it with the same post_title = 'TEST' and i am always getting different results like:

```
Gk16w123clh3RZdYbGZc8g==
L64cWTVSaxWf8xGVVCRbyQ==
Ox2H4xAizS9lsKEQHzxRgg==
```

Is this normal? will i have any kind of issues if i move to a different server in the future?

Comment: why you are encoding?What's the purpose?..

Comment: I see it as an extra security layer in case the db falls in the wrong hands. These are private posts and not public. Of course i am gonna encode the post body also , not only the title :)

Comment: i don't know whether it is correct or not. I am using base64_encode for encoding my strings in url.........But it's secure for my use. I am not sure for this case.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll tell you from my personal experience that it's common when encoding with CodeIgniter (I've used it thousands of times for different purposes), although I don't know exactly why. I've tested it massively with lots of strings and you can rely safely on it.

It works perfect in different servers **as long as you keep the same secret key and the same character encoding**. I you move to a different server in the future the decryption will work fine.

Comment: Thanks! so if i keep my utf-8 setting AND the key i should be fine...I suppose that this base64 magic is happening inside somewhere and that IV key also is different, hence the different strings.